# getting info from the same table on the last join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table, users that contains two type of users. An user can create many works and asign helpers to them. Evey work contains several pages.

user

```
id | name | type
1   john    type1
2   jane    type2
```

work

```
id | name | owner | helper
1    work1    1        2
2    work2    1        2
```

pages

```
id | name | work_id
1    page1   1
2    page2   1
```

How do I get the name owner and helper of a page?

Example, I want all the pages of a work with all the info, including the name of the owner and helper, not jut the ids

```
select p.id, p.name, p.work_id, work.owner as owner, work.helper as helper 
from pages as p
join work on work.id = p.work_id 
join user on user.id = work.owner
where p.work_id = 1
```

Comment: Please provide expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below :

```
select p.id, p.name, p.work_id, a.name as owner, b.name as helper 
from pages as p
join work on work.id = p.work_id 
join user a on a.id = work.owner
join user b on b.id = work.helper
where p.work_id = 1
```

as you can see, you can join twice in different columns and same table.